# What does the pink teddy bear represent in Breaking Bad?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad, props

After the plane crash in season 2 of breaking bad a pink teddy bear falls into Walts pool.

We see the bear in several scenes before the plane crash in previous episodes of the season. In these scenes it is the only element that's in colour. The rest of the scenes are in black and white.

What is the meaning of this bear? What does it represent?

Comment: I was hoping the eyeball was one of those camera Teddy's that actually showed or recorded something significant to the story.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> [Pink Teddy Bear](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Pink_Teddy_Bear) is an homage to the film Schindler's List, in
> which the color red is used to distinguish a little girl in a coat.
>
> Television critic Myles McNutt has called it "a symbol of the damage
> [Walter] feels responsible for.
>
> (source:[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad#Pink_teddy_bear))

So the Pink Teddy Bear is always kept for open interpretation similar to Girl in red in Schindler's List. But I agree with Myles McNutt that it could be a symbol of the damage Walter feels responsible of. That may be the reason he kept eye of the teddy bear.

Comment: Great answer. I would also draw similarities with the innocence of both Jane and the girl with the red coat: They both die because of something that isn't really their fault. Also, after watching Jane die (with his eyes), Walter keeps the eye of the bear. It's hard to say if I'm over analysing or if it was spectacularly well written...

Comment: In the scene where the bear falls into the pool Walt is wearing a pink jumper. I believe its for the first time too. Its probably just a coincidence but they sure did like to use colours for different purposes in the series.

Comment: In fact the answer would have been far better if it would *at least* have included all the stuff that Wikipedia says. As it stands it doesn't even mention the connection to the plane crash that was basically caused by *Jane*'s dad and thus indirectly by *Walt*. Sure that might be obvious to the OP, but this really belongs into the answer. No offense, but while the answer is basically correct, the other answers are really *way* more elaborate. Sometimes too much conciseness doesn't really help an answer.

Comment: @Coomie Don't forget that we also see the pink teddy bear on the big wall painting in *Jane*'s room.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it got covered in "a symbol of the damage [Walter] feels responsible for"

Comment: And also feels its not downvotable for sure :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Meh, sorry, but an answer that merely cites Wikipedia, yet then is even way worse than Wikipedia in the first place, just isn't it. Granted, it's not entirely flawed and might not be worth a downvote, but then again I might have been influenced a bit by the fact that its status as the top-voted and accepted answer is to me completely ununderstandable and I just wanted to balance that a bit. Might not be the best reason for a downvote, but it made the decision for me when it stood on the edge.

Answer (score 15):

The [quote from the creator](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Pink_Teddy_Bear) Vince Gilligan himself:

> The teddy bear eyeball that Walt found in his swimming pool is
>   symbolic. It's very, very symbolic. However, I'm not sure I can tell
>   you with 100% certainty of what the symbolism is, what it
>   represents...On the face of it, when we were coming up with that eye
>   as an image, it probably, represented some form of the eye of the
>   universe, the eye of god, the eye of morality, I suppose judging
>   Walter White...And so symbolism like the eyeball, I'm not sure what it
>   means to me completely but I'm always interested in hearing what it
>   means to viewers of the show. I guess if you're going to hold my feet
>   to the fire, what it means to me is the eye of God on Walt. If not
>   necessarily judging him, nonetheless watching him, keeping tabs on
>   him. And then the question: If that is what the symbolism stands for,
>   then why does Walt keep that eye? Why does he keep it in his drawer
>   versus discarding it?

Answer (score 14):

Just another thought, which probably is nothing more than an interesting connection:

> [image: Bear] [image: Gus]
>  Foreshadowing perhaps?

Comment: I think you mean *coincidence*. Wonderful insight of yours, and I wouldn't be surprised if the special effects team and writers had actually decided to link the two together.

Comment: This needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

Think about it, I think it's spelled out pretty plainly for us with Walter standing there with the pink sweater on.  We're led through the chain reaction of cause and effects, poor decisions and their outcome.  Walter's drive to achieve in an industry that he's completely unfit for (as was pointed out to him by a psycho drug distributor at one point) contributed to Jesse hitting the pipe hard, which led to his girlfriend falling off the wagon and getting on heroin again.

He was even there with the opportunity to save her life as she choked on her vomit, but relented.  Her death then caused her father to drop the ball in his job as an air traffic controller, causing the collision of the planes, which brought Pinky the Bear to his pool, burnt and in pieces.  This at the moment that he's contemplating how he destroyed his own family by the same decision to make bank as a meth producer and dealer; it's a metaphorical collision of disastrous proportions.

Don't forget the unseen victims, the users of his product, which has now spread across the whole South West, as demonstrated in this episode, it's comparable to a couple of airliners full of people colliding in midair, probably worse.

Answer (score 3):

The painted mural over Jane's bedroom has  the exact color and looking bear as the one that fell in Walt's pool. It's a direct reference to his part in Jane's death and those of the airplane passengers.

Answer (score 2):

In re: The pink teddy bear falling from the collision of the two airplanes into Walt's pool: seemingly tangible evidence of the destruction of a small child aboard one of the planes and indication that Walt's choices and actions had increasingly destructive repercussions- far reaching ripples of destruction that he could not have foreseen, but ones that permanently effected even those most innocent.  Finding the doll's eye, so constructed like that of a person, left behind in the filter. would have to eat at the soul of someone who could trace the collision to willful actions of his own.  It would speak of the doll's dead appraisal of Walt's guilt- how even an inanimate object could clearly see and stand witness to the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Pink Teddy Bear left so many things to think. So from all series some of them i found and observed. is like

***Before anything I must say [Vince Gilligan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0319213/?ref_=tt_ov_wr) is Genius.***

> I always call the Teddy Bear Jane's because the plane crash happened
>   because of it and Walt keeps it probably as a award as how much power
>   he has over people

*Kind of Karma.A reminder that what goes around, comes around.*

After finishing all season that Pink Teddy bear & one eye is showing Karma games in latter series.

The Pink Teddy is a child's toy. so it represents innocence apart from that Its pink(perhaps it is pointing to Jesse pink man).Teddy fell from flight, so trying to show Jesse is fall from innocence.The eye becomes the Rogue Eye & its like walter holding those rogue things who don't have longer control of his rogue acts.

- *Jesse got the kind of warning too*

[image]

- Pind Teddy is fall from *Flight 737* & walter needs *737 Dollar*
- of course in this same thread answer
  https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/26386/9676 is also one of the point

[image]

- One more warning or threat to for walter & Jesse is (Gale shot)

[image]

In most of the episodes tried to highlight Pink Teddy bear related thing by color or anything which point to those things

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree about the bear's significance explained above.

Further, to me, the eye has two meanings:

1. The all-seeing eye of God, which sees Walt, and even warns and protects him (e.g. when Mike calls Gus calls the Twins to cancel killing Walt). It also is watching his decisions to tally his later consequences and accountability.
2. Walt keeps it as a reminder  of his connection to the airline crash... and maybe as penance?

Answer (score 0):

So I'd say from reading those two things id say the teddy near represents Walt before he dips his toe in the business and afterwards is burnt in his pool and he holds onto the eye because he regrets the one decision that led to this accident which was originally supposed to symbolize the eye of god, watching him when he was making this decision, and he happened to be at the pool lighting matches and tossing them into his half empty half full pool while making this decision which is foretelling

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. Quick note: that's a big run-on sentence without even a period to finish it. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. *Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.*

Answer (score 0):

Eye of god, the oracle, yes.  More simply it represents and eye for an eye, and even more specifically a symbol for karma or cause and effect in the plot structure.

Answer (score 0):

I've felt that it is not so much the overview of the damage as much as it symbolizes the damage itself. The reason he keeps it in the drawer is because he doesn't want to remember the damage. However, it is impossible to just drop that altogether

Answer (score 0):

Pink bear is fallen innocence.  In the painted image on the wall above Jane's bed, the same pink bear is hovering in the top right.  This bear, and what it represents, has literally fallen into the hands of Walt.

Answer (score -1):

I actually think the teddy bear was a small child from one of the planes Walter being indirectly responsible , It would of been way to horrible to see the Child, Walt saw the child and the implications of his guilt, by psychological disconnection he saw the "Red" teddy bear, 
I'M NOT A PSYCHOLOGIST SO I DON'T KNOW THE CORRECT TERM FOR THIS,
But how many first responders have said "I thought it was a doll/ toy" Including my Fireman friend who told me a Horrific story he had experienced